# Unix - File Search with Regular expression

Tags: regex, unix

```
find . -iname "abc_v?_test.txt" -print
```

Which finds all the files

```
abc_v1_test.txt, abc_v2_test.txt, ..., abc_v9_test.txt
```

But how can I get additionally get `abc_v10_test.txt, abc_v11_test.txt..`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-regex` option as well:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -iregex ".*abc_v[0-9]{1,2}_test\.txt$"
```

Comment: Thanks! But I am unable to display the file names.

Comment: Ya, I couldn't get the files

Comment: Ya, I am not getting the "abc_v10_test.txt" also, I have to get both the file names "abc_v1_test.txt" & "abc_v10_test.txt" that is after "_V" i have to retreive 1 digit or 2 digit numbers followed by "_test.txt"

Comment: I have tested this find command on gnu find and OSX find as well. It finds both the files

Answer (score 0):

You still have the option to get all files and pass them to `grep`, `ack` or `ag`:

```
find . | ag 'abc_v\d+_test\.txt'
```

note you can replace `ag` by `egrep`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have implemented in this way

find . -iname "abc_v*_test.txt" -print.

is there any Regular expression that accepts only 1 or 2 numbers after V?